# Create random number with exponential distribution in c++ (visual stduio)

Tags: c++, exponential-distribution

I am trying to create random number with exponential distribution.
When I tested with a simple example, it worked well.
But when I create it in my project, it does not work. My project include many classes with different objects. 
A class in my project:

User.h:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<math.h>
#include<random>
#include"Packet.h"
using namespace std;

class User {
protected:
    queue<Packet*> PacketList;
    const double rnd = 1.0 / 100;
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    exponential_distribution<> packetArrivalRate(double); // it will be error if "packetArrivalRate(1.0/100)"
public:
    void newPacket();
};
```

User.cpp:

```
#include"User.h";

exponential_distribution<> User::packetArrivalRate(double)
{
    return exponential_distribution<>(rnd);
}

void User::newPacket()
{
    Packet* p = new Packet;
    PacketList.push(p);
    double time = packetArrivalRate(generator); //this line is error
}
```

Can anyone help me to create the "time" with exponentially distributed random number.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: packetArrivalRate expects a double, you give a generator. It returns a exponential_distribution<>, you take a double.

Comment: _"it is not work."_ Please see the Help Centre: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve)."_

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: @sasuke0o01 You are using `rnd` while it is not declared. Seems it should be `exponential_distribution<> User::packetArrivalRate(double rnd)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `packetArrivalRate` with `generator`are the parameter, when the function expects a `double`. Said function return a `exponential_distribution<>` which needs a generator to give you the exponentially distributed numbers.

One simple (and very ugly) way to solve this is to give `packetArrivalRate` a proper argument (note that this argument is completely ignored by the function, so its value doesn't matter), and then call `operator()` on the return value:

```
double time = packetArrivalRate(0)(generator);
```

**Alternative design**

A more reasonable way is to not ignore the argument, and then provide `rnd`:

```
double time = packetArrivalRate(rnd)(generator);
```

And define `packetArrivalRate` like this:

```
exponential_distribution<> User::packetArrivalRate(double lambda)
{
    return exponential_distribution<>(lambda);
}
```

**Random engines**

Please do use a Mersenne Twister pseudo-random generator (`std::mt19937` or `std::mt19937_64`) instead of `std::default_random_engine`. They may provide much better random numbers. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DPkyvkMkk8) by the author of `<random>`.

Comment: Thank you, but It still doesn't work.
My rnd is lambda

Comment: What do you mean by "still doesn't work"? It compiles just fine and does provide exponentially distributed numbers.